# javascript regular expression - remove extra slashes from output

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using RegExp on a pattern after reading it from a json file.

```
json file : 
patternToSearch : {
"test" : "/^test/g"
}
```

In js file I am using this pattern to match with a string

```
var patternToMatch = "testing";

var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch[test]);
console.log(pattern.test(patternToMatch);
```

I get the output as false as instead of `/^test/g` the pattern is coming out as `/\/^test\/g/`.

Not able to remove the extra slahes. Could somebody help me out in this?

Comment: `['test']` I guess test here should be a string instead of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `test` is not defined in your case.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch[test]);
                                              ^  ^
```

You have to replace `test` with a `"test"`.
So this like of code should looks like

```
var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch["test"]);
```

It works too:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch.test);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch[test].replace(/^\/|\/$/g,''));
```

because:

```js
console.log(`/\/^test\/g/`.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''))
```

Single`\`doesn't matter while `/` matters.

And I don't know why you didn't get error using `patternToSearch[test]`.It should be `patternToSearch.test` unless you have defined variable `test`.

So i would suggest you try this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(file.patternToSearch.test.replace(/^\/|\/$/g,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have seen from other answers that accessing a `key` without treating it as a string is wrong. Besides, you should split your original regex into two parts: *patterns* and *flags* then use them in a `RegExp` constructor:

```js
var patternToSearch = {"test":"/^test/g"};
var source = patternToSearch.test.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/);
// source[1] contains patterns, source[2] contains flags
var pattern = new RegExp(source[1], source[2]);
// Logging our tests
console.log(pattern.test("testing"));
console.log(pattern.test("not-testing"));
```

But before doing this, you have to make sure that tokens and escaped characters are double escaped.

Comment: I am reading it from a json file and "patternToSearch" has more keys so can't access it directly with .test.

Comment: That's a thing you should find out. Your main problem is dealing with regex that I tried to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
new RegExp("\^test", "g")
```

I got it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)